# facebook share in sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: publishing-page, social, share, social-feed

I'm trying to configure Facebook, twitter icon on SharePoint Pages.

I have to share SharePoint page on Facebook. Like implemented [here](https://www.buzzfeed.com/andrewgauthier/marathoners-run-to-deliver-supplies-to-hurricane-v?utm_term=.kuVAyPB7P#.glqMo27b2)

so is there any OOTB feature / web part for these social media in SharePoint. 
[image]

I want these social media icons on page, once click on icon SharePoint page will be share on facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOTB there is no such webpart. However, there are lot of plugins available on the Internet which you can use and integrate with on SP pages.

Couple of plugins you can use -

1) [html share buttons](https://simplesharebuttons.com/html-share-buttons/) - this one is simple & easy to integrate. Just add the necessary buttons that you want in a script editor webpart or page layout etc. This however wont provide info about how many were shared.

2) [Addthis](https://www.addthis.com/get/share) - requires registration. Once registered tt provides you with a unique code. This also provides info regarding how many pages were shared on FB, twitter etc.

3) [AddtoAny](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/for/website) - similar to Addthis requires registration. You can select what all social media services you want to share on.

4) [Sharethis](http://www.sharethis.com/) - requires registration. Similar to addthis. Provides a tracking code. You can also implement it like in this SO question [ShareThis Button to Open in Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26301453/862892)

5) [Pure html share buttons](https://schier.co/blog/2014/10/22/pure-html-share-buttons.html)

[Add social sharing buttons to your site](http://mashable.com/2011/03/11/add-social-sharing-buttons/)

Disclaimer - I am not affiliated to any of the above mentioned products in any way.

There are many other plugins also available. You can choose whichever fits your requirement.

Bottomline - To implement them, you will most likely need to add their either provided script in a Script editor webpart or inside a page layout or if you want it across the site, then add it inside your masterpage.

Comment: In email 
<a href="mailto:?subject=HMTL%20Share%20Buttons&body=Hello Sir, Please find the below documents" target="_blank" class="share-btn email">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </a>
Inside body I would like to write message which will display on new line.
IS it possible. because now it display message on same line.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765834/insert-a-line-break-in-mailto-body